# Calculated Column based on multiple other columns that may not exist

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, calculated-column-formula

Is it possible to create a Calculated Column based on other columns that may not exist? Here is the hypothetical scenario.

We have a Term Set such as the following:

```
* Animals
    * Mammals
        * Dog
        * Cat
        * Mouse
    * Birds
       * Parrot
       * Eagle
       * Hawk
    * Fish
        * Salmon
        * Flounder
        * Cod
```

We have a Content Type hierarchy that looks like this:

```
* Animal
    * Mammal
    * Bird
    * Fish
```

The Mammal Content Type has a column called Mammal Type which is a Managed Metadata Field that only allows values from the Mammals level of the Term Set. The Bird and Fish Content Types are set up the same way, with Bird Type and Fish Type columns, respectively.

The parent Content Type, Animal, has a column called Animal Type. We would like to use that column to group documents in a Document Library that contains all three Content Types, Mammal, Bird, and Fish.

It would be ideal if we could create Animal Type as a calculated column that contains the value of Mammal Type if it exists, or Bird Type if it exists, or Fish Type if it exists. I don't know if that's possible. If it is, how would I do that? If not, what other options exist for solving this problem?